# How to limit my String to be between 001 and the max string to 999 implementing conditions once it is read by by user

Tags: java

> //need to set a condition for a read String by user to be between
>   001 and 999
>       String str="000";
>       int i=Integer.parseInt(str);
>       if(i<1||i>999)
>         System.out.print("error");

Comment: `if (!str.matches("\\d+") || Integer.valueOf(str) < 1 || Integer.valueOf(str) > 999) { System.out.println("ERROR! - Invalid Input Value!"); }`.

Comment: this code accepts string less that 3 characters. it should accept the range 001 -999. thanx for the help much appreciated

Comment: Then just add the required number of digits to the regular expression used in the **matches()** method: `if (!str.matches("\\d{3}") || Integer.valueOf(str) < 1 || Integer.valueOf(str) > 999) { System.out.println("ERROR! - Invalid Input Value!"); }` OR add yet another condition to validate length: `if (!str.matches("\\d+") || str.length() != 3 || Integer.valueOf(str) < 1 || Integer.valueOf(str) > 999) { System.out.println("ERROR! - Invalid Input Value!"); }`.

Comment: @DevilsHnd If the string matches `"\\d{3}"`, how can it be `> 999`? --- If `length() == 3` how can it be `> 999`? --- Wouldn't `if (! str.matches("(?!0{3})\\d{3}"))` cover it all, i.e. 3 digits but not 3 zeroes?

Comment: It can't... that condition can be obviously be **eliminated** from both **if** statements. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score -1):

```
private boolean isStrInRange(String str){
    return IntStream.range(1, 999)
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            .contains(Integer.parseInt(str));
}
```

I think this is the best way, using Stream API